# Simple way to loop through ruby on rails array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could someone point me in the right direction about looping through an array and extracting the required values. It's causing me issues understanding it:

```
array = [{"response_message"=>nil, "response_client_message"=>nil, "response_customer_message"=>nil, "closed"=>true, "updated_at"=>2012-05-30 13:20:49 UTC, "created_at"=>2012-05-30 13:20:29 UTC, "token"=>"2fda85eab962fa6e27850605f2f948ca", "price"=>"$24.00", "amount"=>#<BigDecimal:7fa3f4485428,'0.24E2',9(18)>, "currency_code"=>"USD", "metadata"=>"{\"xxx\": 5, \"xxx\": 250, \"xxx\": true, \"support\": { \"email\": true, \"phone\": false } }", "line_items"=>[{"amount"=>#<BigDecimal:7fa3f4482fe8,'0.24E2',9(18)>, "notes"=>nil, "currency_code"=>"USD", "description"=>"1 day", "price"=>"$24.00", "feature_level"=>"{\"hotspots\": 5, \"vouchers\": 250, \"customizable_logins\": true, \"support\": { \"email\": true, \"phone\": false } }", "metadata"=>"{\"hotspots\": 5, \"vouchers\": 250, \"customizable_logins\": true, \"support\": { \"email\": true, \"phone\": false } }"}]}]
```

One of these is generated each day, I need to loop through and present a few values. I've tried this:

```
array.select{|elem| elem[:updated_at]}
```

But that gives me a [].

How do I loop through this and extract the values?
I also need to understand how to get the line_items array out too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.select{|elem| elem["updated_at"]}
```

pass string not a symbol

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're after, but if you want to extract values from that array, try `map`:

```
array.map { |elem| elem["updated_at"] }
```

This will return you a list of all the "updated_at" values.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop through an array and collect the updated_at values, then you should use the collect/map method.
In your example you are referencing elem[:updated_at] which is not the same as elem["updated_at"]

```
array.collect{|elem| elem["updated_at"]}
```